# Search if a string exists in another string

Tags: php

for my purposes I did this:

```
<?php
$mystring = 'Gazole,';
$findme   = 'Sans Plomb 95';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

if ($pos >= 0) {
    echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
    echo " and exists at position $pos";
} else {
    echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
}
?>
```

However, it always executes this branch:

```
echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
echo " and exists at position $pos";
```

although the string I 'm searching for doesn't exist.

Please help, thx in advance :))

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The correct way to do it is:

```
if ($pos !== false) {
    echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
    echo " and exists at position $pos";
} else {
    echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
}
```

See the [giant red warning](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#refsect1-function.strpos-returnvalues) in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

`strpos` returns a boolean `false` in case the string was not found. Your test should be `$pos !== false` rather than `$pos >= 0`.

Note that the standard comparison operators do not consider the type of the operands, so that `false` is coerced to `0`. The `===` and `!==` operators yield `true` only if the types and the values of the operands match.

Answer (score 1):

See the warning on the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

You need also to check if `$pos !== false`

Answer (score 1):

strpos() returns FALSE if the string was not found. 
When you check for $pos >= 0, you're accpeting that FALSE value.

Try this:

```
<?php
$mystring = 'Gazole,';
$findme   = 'Sans Plomb 95';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);


if ($pos !== false) {
    echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
    echo " and exists at position $pos";
} else {
       echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

hi malek strpos method in php will return a boolean of value false when the string is not found and if found it will return the position in int.

refer this [Link to study about strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (strpos($mystring, $findme) !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Completely different way to do it without worrying about indexes:

```
if (str_replace($strToSearchFor, '', $strToSearchIn) <> $strToSearchIn) {
    //strToSearchFor is found inside strToSearchIn
```

What you are doing is replacing out any occurrence of the substring and checking if the result is the same as the original string.